# How to add <b> tag in HTML helper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am try add `<b>` tag inside `<a>` in cake php

I need output like that

```
<a href="/carsdirectory/users/logout"><b>Logout</b></a>
```

but i dont how to add  tag in this code

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Logout', '/users/logout'); ?>
```

Comment: IF you use the helper (which has its advantages, of course), you should use the array syntax, though. otherwise you are destroying part of the power of cakephp's routing.

Comment: Mr Mark, i dont no how use array in this thing

Comment: I added the code example to the correct answer

Comment: I for example then use the following route: `Router::connect('/login/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));` => `http://domain.com/login/` which is pretty need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please keep in mind that styling should not be part of your HTML Output and - as already suggested by my previous posters - should be in your CSS.

However, there you go (note the `escape=false`):

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    '<b>' . __('Logout') . '</b>',
    array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action'     => 'logout',
    ),
    array(
        'escape' => false,
    )
);
```

or even more HtmlHelper magick:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->tag('b', __('Logout')),
    array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action'     => 'logout',
    ),
    array(
        'escape' => false,
    )
);
```

Edit: added Ish Kumar's suggestion for localisation, in cakephp 2.0 we don't need the "true" anymore ;)

One more thing: if you use `escape=false` keep in mind to *sanitize* the tags content (in this case the `<b>Logout</b>`) by *yourself*, especially if its generated user content e.g. `<b>$userInputVar</b>`.

Comment: `$this->Html->tag('b', __('Logout', true))` is good if you need to translation function.

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be don't try to use the helpers for every single task, additionally you should use CSS to add bold to the logout link.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Logout', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'logout'), array('class' => 'logout'));
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.logout {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Update: If you REALLY REALLY must use deprecated HTML tags in your code:**

```
echo $this->Html->link('<b>Logout</b>', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'logout'), array('class' => 'logout', 'escape' => false));
```

Comment: +1 for KISS. After all, what's wrong with just typing out the link itself?

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: there is a bracket too much (after logout)!

Comment: i need result like that 
<a href="/carsdirectory/users/logout"><b>Logout</b></a> not like that <b><a href="/carsdirectory/users/logout">Logout</a></b>

Comment: And with full array syntax it would be: `$this->Html->link('Logout', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'logout'), array('class' => 'logout'));`

Comment: Updated my answer with the full array syntax. The extra bracket was there because I was expecting the array syntax!

Comment: +1 for the "don't try to use the helpers for every single task". However, the `<b>` tag is in not deprecated, but often misused (see http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags)

Answer (score 0):

That's the equivalent of doing this:

```
<b><?php echo $this->Html->link('Logout', '/users/logout'); ?></b>
```

As Dunhamzzz noted, you're better off using a CSS class and styling it that way.

Comment: thanks for reply but i need output like that  <a href="/carsdirectory/admin/users/logout">
<b>Logout</b>
</a>